# Why are obsolete/retired badges still being awarded?

Tags: support, badges

I just read the full list of [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), and see that the [Analytical badge can't be awarded anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183128/analytical-badge-still-showing-faq/183243#183243).

Nevertheless, I discover that some people are [still awarded this badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1306/analytical). How is it possible?

Comment: Those accounts are merged. Their profile descriptions say "merge keep".

Comment: Wondered whether [this hack](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109417/how-come-i-can-award-badges-to-myself-without-meeting-the-requirements) still works but doesn't appear to!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

When two accounts are merged, badges from the deleted account are re-awarded to the kept account.

This includes badges that can no longer be earned on a site; as a rule, if one of your merged accounts had a badge, your newer account will have it too.