# How are users still earning Documentation badges?

Tags: support, documentation, badges

I see people earning Documentation badges; for example, [the Backer badge has been awarded to several users recently](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5849/backer).

However, when I went to Documentation, it didn't let me do anything. It says that "we are not accepting contributions to Documentation".

So, how are people earning these badges? Is there any other way that is not listed?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation

Comment: Well that post doesn't help me. Am i missing something in there ?

Comment: Not an exact answer (otherwise, i would have proposed it as a duplicate) but if you read the whole thing - you should be able to find your answers.  Specifically `We will stop accepting contributions to Documentation on August 8` and everything listed under `What happens to badges?`

Comment: That does not explain how people are still getting badges. https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5849/backer this link shows someone earned this badge yesterday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is likely that people merged two accounts and one of them had a Backer badge.

[See this related answer for the Analytical badge.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261116/3151675)

Comment: I don't think so. It is unlikely that all these people merged accounts IMO

Comment: Look at the statistics of the [Analytical badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1306/analytical). People are still earning it because of profile merging, despite its retirement in June 2013.

Comment: Yeah you are right. A look at the dates of badges they earned proves this. They have a lot of badges that they earned on that single day. Which proves this point.

Comment: Indeed, this is correct. Excellent deduction.